# APP crashes with error “**Collection set was mutated while enumerating** on fetching request from Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have two different xml parsers ParserA & Parser B and I am using coredata

I start with Parser A, where I check whether that record exists in the db , if it exists i update the existing entity else I create a new entity.

After completing parsing with Parsing A, repeat the parsing using Parser B and follow the same process.

My problem is my app randomly crashes, with error “**Collection set was mutated while enumerating** “, when I am fetching request to check the existing record

```
 - (Product *)productForId:(NSString*)productId{

   Product *produc = nil;

   NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext  =dataManager.coreDataHelper.context;

   NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                             entityForName:@"BSProduct" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

   [_fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

   [_fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productId == '%@'", productId]];

   NSError *error;
   NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:_fetchRequest error:&error];

   for (Product *prod in [array copy]){
     return prod;
   }
   return produc;
 }
```

It crashes on line

```
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:_fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: Are you using multiple threads/queues?

Comment: This crash is where you are enumerating a collection object (`NSSet`, `NSArray`) usually for a `for` loop and then you also try to modify the array (i.e. add object, remove object e.t.c) as it is being enumerated. Objective-C fast enumeration can be a cause of this as it enumerates the array as it loops, to overcome this you can use a traditional `for` loop i.e. `for(int i = 0; i < array.count; i++){}`. However, it would be most productive to work out where the code that modifies the array originates from.

Comment: Yes philip I am using multiple threads